# Heroku Javascript runtime error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Copied from my log file

ActionView::Template::Error (Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes.

I'm not planning on using execjs as a runtime for my application. How can I avoid this problem?

In my Gemfile I commented the following two lines out, but I had no effect:

```
# gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
# gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem after a six month hiatus from using Heroku.
It turned out I needed to use the 'cedar' stack and change the deployment URL to use the new installation.
In my app directory:

```
heroku create --stack cedar
git remote set-url heroku git@heroku.com:blooming-river-1759.git
git push heroku master
```

http://dsimard.posterous.com/assets-problems-with-heroku-and-rails-31

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar